# Find Recent Media on Instagram by Tags and not location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

How would I search Instagram for all photos associated with a tag instead of latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1):

The [api](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) has documentation for that, should be pretty straight forward.

EDIT: Instagram has its own [gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem), just require that to implement it in your app. As far as using it to search by tag, the [`Client::Tags`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/master/Instagram/Client/Tags#tag_search-instance_method) module has the methods for you to do that.

Comment: Well, how would I integrate that into my application? I want the model to pull in photos with tags that users input.